# How to add default text to a TableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Currently, I have a `TableView` set up like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        emulatorSettings()
        tableView.reloadData()
        self.reloadInputViews()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: K.cellNibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: K.cellIdentifier)
        if let leftPostArray = userDefaults.array(forKey: fbLeftKey) as? [String]{
            votedLeftPosts = leftPostArray
        }
        if let rightPostArray = userDefaults.array(forKey: fbRightKey) as? [String]{
            votedRightPosts = rightPostArray
        }
        postQuery = Firestore.firestore()
            .collectionGroup("userPosts")
            .order(by: "postTime", descending: false)
            .limit(to: 3)
        
        loadMessages()
    }
```

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Trigger pagination when scrolled to last cell
        if (indexPath.row == posts.count - 1) {
            paginate()
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PostCell
        cell.delegate = self
        
        postBrain.createPost(tableView, post, cell, self.storageRef)
        
        return cell
    }
```

I am trying to make it so that when the table view is empty a label is shown which instructs the user on what to do. I tried adding a label in my Storyboard but that did not work and I also tried creating an alternate .xib file, but that failed as well. I have not been able to find any information on this, can anyone help me out? I know I have done this before in android, is this not something that Apple design recommends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do the following:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//If there are no post you'll create a cell to put the instructions on how to proceed in.
 if posts.count == 0{ 
     return 1
 } else {
        return posts.count
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var post: PostStruct
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PostCell
        cell.delegate = self
        
        if posts.count == 0{
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Instructions"
        }else {
            post = posts[indexPath.row]
            postBrain.createPost(tableView, post, cell, self.storageRef)
            cell.textLabel?.text = ""
        }
        
        return cell
    }
```

This way when you don't have any posts (your table view is empty), you have 1 cell you can put your instructions in.

If you want to show a label, I'd suggest creating a UIView custom class with a label/textview inside of it where you'll write down all of the instructions and you can display it if posts.count == 0.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is to manually add UILabel on top of the tableView, and show/hide it depending on the state.

```swift
// in your view controller declaration
private lazy var emptyStateLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = "Nothing to show :("
    label.textAlignment = .center
    // Customise the label here the way you want!
    return label
}()
```

Set it up in your viewDidLoad

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // ...
    // to make sure its not covered by the table view
    view.insertSubview(emptyStateLabel, aboveSubview: tableView) 
    // or simply
    view.addSubview(emptyStateLabel) 
    // and constraint it anywhere you want, for example in the middle of the view
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        emptyStateLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingConstraint, constant: 16),
        emptyStateLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16)
        emptyStateLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
    ])
    // ...
}
```

then everytime you call `loadMessages`, on its completion change the label alpha depending on the count of the `posts`

```swift
emptyStateLabel.alpha = posts.count == 0 ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this third - party as well.

[DZNEmptyDataSet](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet)

Also, if you want to do that by yourself, this would be really helpful

[Handle Empty Tableview](https://medium.com/@mtssonmez/handle-empty-tableview-in-swift-4-ios-11-23635d108409)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `UIView` on top of your `UITableView`, hidden by default, in which you place your instructions.

You should set its constraints relative to the Superview.

[image: constraints]

Then link it in your view controller.

```
@IBOutlet weak var helpLayout: UIView!
```

Then hide and show it when you update your table view data:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    helpLayout.isHidden = posts.count > 0

    return posts.count
}
```